# How to handle URL containing slash within the input parameters

Tags: jboss

I am working on a Web Service, in which the URL is given with 2 inputs-- input1 & input2 such as . The input2 contains a slash within it like  onj\hjk. When I hit the URL, it is considering as 3 input parameters which is supposed to be only 2. Can you please let me know how to handle this situation and how the code has to be changed accordingly

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating the URLs from Javascript then use either `encodeURIComponent(str)` or `encodeURI(str)` . 
But in case your are generating URLs through PHP then use `urlencode()` .

For details visit [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and  [encodeURI(uri)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp)